# Visited days calendar is disabled/bug on Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

I am trying to check the calendar functionality (visited days) on the profile page. It looks like it's not working and the functionality is disabled(?).

I am seeing this on [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) 56.0.3051.52 and did not check in another browser. Before, Visited days looked like in green shade.

Is it a bug or is it disabled for me?

[image: Visited Days]

Comment: This is the look i've always been accustomed to. Circled date means you visited, blank means you didn't.

Comment: @Magisch If you have remembered well then visited days was seeing as green. I believe this does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Magisch Example of what the calendar used to look like: [ChrisF's answer to: "
How can I see which days I visited site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128606/363946)

Comment: This seems to be network wide, but there is no MSE question about it.

Comment: Inspecting the HTML, all of them get `ui-state-disabled` even for visited's `ui-state-active`. However, removing `ui-state-disabled` doesn't make the visited days back to green (CSS rule also got overwritten?)

Comment: Same for my account (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc): I don't see any green squares anymore.

Comment: On MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317546/visited-calendar-on-profile-empty

Comment: I am pretty sure this is by design. Green color is probably too much "fun", and they make the design as standard (aka boring) as possible. Gray/empty is exactly this and appears more "professional".

Comment: I think the days we visited are outlined.

Comment: Five years on SO and I had no idea this calendar was even a thing. A pity it's the ugly jQuery-style calendar.

Comment: @TylerH jQuery UI won't be eradicated without a fight

Comment: I'm a big fan of light-grey indicators for things that aren't disabled...

Comment: It's still green for me... Maybe I've just got cached CSS or something.

Comment: When I first checked mine after this post, it was same as OP, grey. Today I checked it back again, guess what, it's green again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated Answer:

This is now [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317666/253521):

> Fixed, related to a lot of back-end furniture moving. Kermit isn't just an old file transfer protocol, it's also the name of a frog, that appreciated all things green.
>
> The calendar now pays subtle, tacit attribute to both things, or even your favorite bright green thing, again.
>
> - Tim Post

---

Original Answer:

The calendar shows the days you have visited with a darker grey outline around each day square. As you can see from your screenshot, at the time of your post (Oct 30th), you had visited for two consecutive days, the 29th and 30th. If you log in today, the 31st will have a darker border around it as well, and your profile will say "3 consecutive days" instead. Had you visited on Sunday, your 'consecutive days' visited would have been 10 as of yesterday.

This was [clearly styled differently in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128606/253521), but I don't yet know why or when it changed. I'm sure all the sites' calendars are nearly identical now since the recent rollout of a standardized theme.

Answer (score 3):

The Green shades back in calendar. While inspecting the HTML, Making the class background color green as important. I believe before it was there.

```
.user-show-new .user-header .data .days-visited .ui-state-active span{
  background-color: #339933 !important;
}
```

[image: Calender]